# How can I center the text in my table, so the information is closer in the pdf?

Tags: tables

I have programmed the following table in my document, but there is so much space between each column.

[image]

I would like to reduce the horizontal space so it looks nicer. Jut like this example.

[image]

My code is below and any suggestion(s) are more than welcome.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \caption{ Radiometric and photometric units for light intensity characterization. Radiometric units describe the absolute radiant energy, whereas photometric describe brightness as perceived by the human eye. }
        \label{tbl:radiometri_photometric}
        \begin{center}
            
            \begin{tabular}{*{6}{p{.16\linewidth}}}
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{6}{c}{Radiometric} \\
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{2}{p{.33\linewidth}}{Symbol} & \multicolumn{2}{p{.33\linewidth}}{Quantity} & 
                \multicolumn{2}{p{.33\linewidth}}{Unit} \\
                \midrule
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{$\Phi_e$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Radiant flux} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\si{\watt}} \\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{$E_e$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Irradiance} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\si{\watt\per\square\meter}} \\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{$I_e$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Radiant intensity} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\si{\watt\per\steradian}} \\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{$L_e$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Radiance} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\si{\watt\per(\square\meter\cdot\steradian)}} \\
                \bottomrule
                \\
                %\toprule
                \multicolumn{6}{c}{Photometric} \\
                %\toprule
                %\multicolumn{3}{p{.49\linewidth}}{School} & \multicolumn{3}{p{.49\linewidth}}{State} & 
                %\multicolumn{2}{p{.33\linewidth}}{Unit} \\
                \midrule
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{$\Phi_v$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Luminous flux} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lumen (lm)=\si{\candela\cdot\steradian}} \\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{$E_v$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Illuminance} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lux(lx)=\si{\candela\cdot\steradian\per\square\meter}} \\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{$I_v$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Luminous intensity} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Candela (cd) = \si{lm\per\steradian}} \\
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{$L_v$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Luminance} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Nit (nt) = \si{\candela\per\square\meter}} \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: why not use 3 columns instead of 6

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to switch the first two table rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{ Radiometric and photometric units for light intensity characterization. Radiometric units describe the absolute radiant energy, whereas photometric describe brightness as perceived by the human eye. }
\label{tbl:radiometri_photometric}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Radiometric} \\
    \midrule
    Symbol & Quantity & Unit \\
    \midrule
    $\Phi_e$ & Radiant flux & \si{\watt} \\
    $E_e$ & Irradiance & \si{\watt\per\square\meter} \\
    $I_e$ & Radiant intensity & \si{\watt\per\steradian} \\
    $L_e$ & Radiance & \si{\watt\per(\square\meter\cdot\steradian)} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{Photometric} \\
    \midrule
    $\Phi_v$ & Luminous flux & Lumen (lm)=\si{\candela\cdot\steradian} \\
    $E_v$ & Illuminance & Lux(lx)=\si{\candela\cdot\steradian\per\square\meter} \\
    $I_v$ & Luminous intensity & Candela (cd) = \si{lm\per\steradian} \\
    $L_v$ & Luminance & Nit (nt) = \si{\candela\per\square\meter} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]